# Check either someone has liked a post or not within the template django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have this model struture:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1200, blank=True)

class PostLike(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Template

```
for post in posts
...
# want to check here, something like:
if post.userliked write something endif
...
endfor
```

Now what I want is to check either the current loggedin user has liked the post or not within the django template.

I have tried, `post.postlike_set` but of course that won't work because it's for all the likes, is there anyway that I can check if the current loggedin user has liked the post or not.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `likes` in a [many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) while accessing this field and `user` (as the owner of the post) field with [FK related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')
    text = models.TextField()
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')
```

This way we can access `Post` created by an `User` with `user.posts.all()` and all posts liked by an `User` with `user.likes.all()`

views.py

```
def posts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'posts.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Since you want to check the logged in user, we do not need to pass it by context, instead we access it directly in template using the `request` object.

posts.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    <p>{{post}}</p>
        {% if post in request.user.likes.all %}
            <p> You already liked this post </p>
        {% else %}
            <button>Like</button>
        {% endif %}
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```